# Is there a sequential version of probabilistic latent semantic analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, online-algorithms, sequential-analysis, latent-semantic-analysis

Does someone know if it exists some way to do online learning with [pLSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_latent_semantic_analysis)? The model training is really time consuming, so it is not feasible to rebuild it after every changes in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5279464) and [that](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-19309-5_8). The application might be different from yours, but I bet you can still get something useful out of them.

The basic idea is to upgrade the EM algorithm used to learn the parameters with an incremental version.